# can't access the data from service in controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-service

I am trying to add [angular-typeahead](https://github.com/Siyfion/angular-typeahead) to my app for search suggestion taking help from this [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/cMvm7Z4REuIP69Uk4Tzz).

This is the code of app.js file:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute','siyfion.sfTypeahead']);

myApp.factory('websitesSvc',function($http, $log, $q) {
return {
    getwebsites: function(){

        //Create a promise using promise library
        var deferred = $q.defer();

        $http({method: 'GET', url: '/api/websites/'}).
            success(function(data, status, headers,config){
                deferred.resolve(data);
            }).
            error(function(data, status, headers,config){
                deferred.reject(status);
            });

        return deferred.promise;
    }
};
});

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope','websitesSvc',
function($scope,websitesSvc) {

$scope.searchString=null;


websitesSvc.getwebsites().then(function(websites){
 $scope.websites = websites;
 console.log($scope.websites); //It works here
}); 

//Output undefined
//THIS IS NOT WORKING

console.log($scope.websites); 



var websites = new Bloodhound({
datumTokenizer: function(d) { return Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace(d.domain_name); },
queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,

//want to pass the websites array list from service to local 
local:websites, //THIS IS NOT WORKING
});

// initialize the bloodhound suggestion engine
 websites.initialize();

$scope.numbersDataset = {
displayKey: 'domain_name',
 source: websites.ttAdapter()
};

// Typeahead options object
$scope.exampleOptions = {
 highlight: true
}; 

 }
]);
```

The thing is the I am not able to pass the value of `$scope.websites` to the `typeahead`.How to make get the value of websites from services so that I can pass the resultant array to the `typeahead`?

After editing the code as suggested by red 6 hours ago Kalhano Toress Pamuditha, I am able to access the data.But now I am getting this [image: Console Error]

Answer (score 1):

```
websitesSvc.getwebsites().then(function(websites){
   $scope.websites = websites;
   console.log($scope.websites); //It works here
});


//Output undefined
//THIS IS NOT WORKING

console.log($scope.websites);                 this will execute before   websitesSvc.getwebsites() completes,
```

javascript code is not hold until sync calls to be complete it will execute the rest of the code, that is the case where u get the undefined.

you will get the data after `websitesSvc.getwebsites()` promise. so if u need to execute something after this data received, you can execute a function inside `then` like below

```
  websitesSvc.getwebsites().then(function(websites){
     $scope.websites = websites;
     console.log($scope.websites); //It works here
     $scope.methodAfterComplete();
 });  
 $scope.methodAfterComplete = function() {
     // this will call after completing the websitesSvc.getwebsites()
 }
```

so you can place your code inside `methodAfterComplete` method which require `$scope.websites` data. for example ;

```
 $scope.methodAfterComplete = function() {
     var websites = new Bloodhound({
       datumTokenizer: function(d) { return Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace(d.domain_name); },
        queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
               local:websites,
       });

      // initialize the bloodhound suggestion engine
       websites.initialize();

     $scope.numbersDataset = {
     displayKey: 'domain_name',
      source: websites.ttAdapter()
    };

    // Typeahead options object
     $scope.exampleOptions = {
        highlight: true
     }; 
 }
```

Comment: When I put the `angular-typeahead` in this function and `console.log($scope.websites)` it prints the array to the console.But I am getting `TypeError: Cannot set property 'highlight' of undefined` in the console.

Comment: Can u please see this http://plnkr.co/edit/cMvm7Z4REuIP69Uk4Tzz?p=preview and suggest the modifications required in my code.I did same as in plunkr but getting error.

Comment: I did the same as you suggested except `local:$scope.websites` as `console.log(websites)` was printing undefined.But still its giving  `TypeError: Cannot set property 'highlight' of undefined` in the console. What's wrong in this ?